# How do I present a JSQMessagesViewController with the keyboard already up?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm using an [open source messaging UI library](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController) for an app that I'm building. When users start a new conversation I want the "chat view" to appear with the keyboard already up and the cursor on the textfield (similar to most existing chat applications). Is there a way to force the `JSQMessagesViewController` to appear with the keyboard already up?

I tried implementing this using:

```
self.keyboardController.textView.becomeFirstResponder()
```

However, this caused the keyboard to pop up immediately when the view was presented... yet the toolbar would lag behind by about a second (not too much, but painfully noticeable). In addition, this solution seems to disable the keyboard from being dismissed using a downward gesture as it normally does.

Is there something I'm missing that solves this out of box? Or will I have to modify the library to get this bit of functionality... and if so, where do I begin doing that?

Answer (score 0):

try to do like this

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
      [super viewWillAppear:YES];
      [myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

--> It will make focus on myTextField and open the keyboard automatically. Hope it may help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I just tried this and it suffers from the exact same issues as putting .becomeFirstResponder in the viewDidLoad function -> textField lags behind and suppresses the keyboard from being dismissed via downward gesture.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. It's in swift, but should be easy to translate.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(false)

    self.inputToolbar!.contentView!.textView!.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: This worked for you as in the textfield does not lag behind the keyboard coming up? Because for me this is behaving exactly the same as my solution and the solution from Er. Kukadiya below.

Comment: It caused the to pop up together instead of the textfield coming in after the keyboard. There is still the short delay, but they arrive at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted this with a button click so I added:

```
[self.inputToolbar.contentView.textView becomeFirstResponder];
```

If you want yours when it loads add:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self.inputToolbar.contentView.textView becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This maybe too late, but in my case I forgot to call `super.viewDidAppear(animated)` which caused text view to lag behind keyboard. Once I added that call, problem went away.

Comment: This was my answer to the problem. And I clicked 'Add Another Answer'.